# Is there a way to get the summary section from a form into a Google Doc

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs, google-forms

I've got a survey using Google Forms and it has useful graphs in it's summary section (under responses). How can I get these graphs into a Google Doc? I tried downloading the CSV file and recreating the graphs in a Google spreadsheet and this didn't even work properly.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid that is not possible by downloading the "images" since these are not "actual" images but dynamically generated visual representations.

### Workaround

You "*tried downloading the CSV file*", which means you would be getting a static "image".
In that case, your easiest **working** alternative would be to **use a screen-capture application/addon** to capture a selected area, save locally and then insert the captured image to your Google Doc.